# Why does a function that returns int not need a prototype?

Tags: c

I tried this program on DevC++ that would call two different types of function, one returning `int` and  one returning `char`. I'm confused why the `int` function doesn't need a prototype, while the `char` one and any other type of function does.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//int function1();
char function2() ;

int main (){
    int X = function1() ;
    char Y = function2() ;
    
    printf("%d", X) ;
    printf ("%c", Y) ;
    
    return 0 ;
}

int function1(){
    return 100 ;
}

char function2(){
    return 'B' ;
}
```

The output:

```
100B
```

If I remove the prototype for the `char` function, it results in:

```
[Error] conflicting types for 'function2'
[Note] previous implicit declaration of 'function2' was here
```

Comment: Never write functions without prototypes. Functions without prototypes have arguments passed to them differently than functions with prototypes.  If you don't understand why you don't need a prototype for a function that returns `int`, then complexities and potential bugs caused by that difference in how arguments get passed are something you have to avoid.  Look up "default argument promotion".

Comment: @louisnot That error is because your definition contradicts this implicit declaration. See what happens when you rely on this for a library function and that function actually returns `void` or a `long long`. Your compiler won't see a contradiction, and during runtime your stack will get corrupted. You should heed the warnings.

Comment: @AndrewHenle But no arguments are passed, so that is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @Cheatah Until arguments are added - then it's critically relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the old days of C any function that was not declared explicitely was supposed to return `int` type when you call it.
If the compiler then finds the function implementation and sees an `int` return type, everything is fine.
If the function returns anything else than `int` you get the error message as you saw with the second function.

This implicit `int` type declaration was removed from the standard with C99. Now you should at least get a warning from your compiler when you use a function without prototype.

If you did not get any diagnostic message for first funcion, you should turn up warning level in your compiler or switch to at least C99 mode instead of ancient versions.

Edit:
Empty parameter lists in funcion definitions is a deprecated feature as well.
You should not use it.
Always provide prototype for every function with return type and parameter list.

Answer (score 6):

If a function is used before it is declared, the usage becomes an **implicit declaration** of the function.  When a function `f` is implicitly defined, the definition given to it is `int f()`, i.e. a function which accepts an unspecified number of arguments and returns an `int`.

This implicit definition of a function matches the actual definition of `function1` but not `function2`.  So calling `function1` this way gives no error but attempting to call `function2` this way results in the implicit definition not matching the actual definition, giving an error.

This behavior goes back to pre-standardized versions of C where all objects (and a function's return type) had a default type of `int` if not declared.  This was still present in the C89 standard but removed in the C99 standard, although some compilers such as gcc still support this obsolescent usage as an extension.

Answer (score 3):

It's just an ancient relic from when C was first designed. It was actually removed as early as C99, but many compilers still support this type of declaration. But it's not recommended to use it.

I'm not sure if there were any real rationale behind it, but C was heavily inspired by the language B. And in B you did not have to specify the return type for functions. That actually made perfect sense, because there was only one type, `word`.

In the same way you did not have to specify the type of variables either. You only specified if it had automatic or static storage. And that's where the completely useless keyword `auto` in C comes from. It does not mean the same as in C++. It just means "not static".